# Is there a way to limit the text input length in $mdDialog.prompt() in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

It's all in the title. The cursor hitting a wall (so to speak) would be much better than the dialog box closing, checking the input length, and then telling the user they have to type everything over again, just less text, because they typed too much.

Answer (score 0):

I have sort of worked around the validation problem here, I get its not idea, But just pass the entered in text back into the model

```
        $scope.generateUpdatedDocumentButtonClicked = function (ev, textContentValue) {
        var versionNumber = $scope.data.Version + 0.1;

        var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt()
            .title('New Test Document Version')
            .textContent(textContentValue)
            .initialValue(versionNumber)
            .targetEvent(ev)
            .required(true)
            .ok('Generate')
            .cancel('Cancel');

        $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function (result) {
            if (//validate to be true) {
                $scope.generateUpdatedDocument(result);
            } else
            {
                $scope.generateUpdatedDocumentButtonClicked(ev, 'Value Invalid');
            }

        }, function () {
            alert('Cancel Clicked');
        });
    }
```

The initial call to the fuction will pass in a empty string.
Again this is not great but works around my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can just prevent to type more than N symbols using HTML5 **maxLength** input feature

`<input type="text" maxlength="5">`

So user would be unable to type more than 5 symbols, as an example.